# Zabbix Scripts with empty return

Tags: bash, zabbix, nmap

I made a simple script for checking ports with NMAP, which returns 1 if the port is open, and 0 if it is closed. I'm trying to create an item in zabbix that runs this script. In tests, I can run the script successfully through the Zabbix UI, but it returns an empty value  after execution. I am able to run the script normally via CLI, I have no permission issues either. I would like some help diagnosing what might be going on.

Here is the script zabbix-nmap.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=$(nmap $1 -p $2)
SUB='open'
if [[ "$PORT" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
  echo 1
else
  echo 0
fi
```

Here is the Zabbix Item template configuration/test
[Zabbix Item Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46gHK.png)
[Zabbix Item Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeZzK.png)

I tried to run the file as root and as a zabbix user via cli and I can do it normally, via UI the script execution test also does not show an error, but returns an empty result.

Comment: why dont you just use zabbix agent buildtin `net.tcp.port[<ip>,port]` ?

Comment: Using this simple check it works like a charm! Tnx!